# AS 3 isolib Game development

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, flash, isometric

I need to develop a isometric game on facebook like farmvillie, barnbuddy or etc. 
I found couple of frame works [(link is here)](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2010/02/23/11-flash-isometric-engines-you-can-use-in-your-games/) to develop it, but they not simple as isolib.
So I decided to go with as3 isolib. 
Google project for that is [here](http://code.google.com/p/as3isolib/).

But I could not find a A-Z tutorial for as3 isolib, except basic (adding scenes, adding map and etc). 
I want more stuff. So Can you please suggest me a advance as3 isolib tutorial (I googled it 100 times) ?

Anyway if you have suggestion for frame work except isolib to develop isometric game,let me know it also.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**as3isolib** is a great library, I've used in a few projects (not games though) with a lot of success, so I would highly recommend it. I guess you've found the [tutorial list on the library's wiki](http://code.google.com/p/as3isolib/w/list), they're basic but cover most of the stuff you'll need. Besides those, I got started using as3isolib [with this tutorial](http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/games/build-an-isometric-map-editor-with-as3isolib/), which is a little specific but gives quite a few hints on some useful things like texture assets, isometric coordinates, etc. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks lot for your help. I am looking forward those.